# django reduce query load time

Tags: python, django, nginx

I using nginx as server.

While loading the simple html page without any queries using Django , It takes only 34 milliseconds to load.

```
<html><body><h1> Test</h1></body></html>
```

If run some queries ( having 500 rows in query) it take 4 seconds to load the page.

views.py

```
def testing3(request):
        context = User.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('pages/index1.html',  {'users': context,})
```

index1.html

```
<html>
<head> <title>Testing  </title>    </head>
<body>
Testing
<h1>Testing</h1>
{% for e in users %}
<table>
        <tr> <td class="active">{{ e.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ e.email }}</td>    </tr>
</table>
        {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

How to reduce the loading time.
[image]

How to reduce this waiting time?

Comment: Try using SQL query to get data?

Comment: You should use a Django ListView with pagination to display only few users by page.

Comment: Are you actually just displaying 500 Users or other models that possibly do additional complex SQL operations?

Comment: @PhucTran You mean I have to use raw_sql?

Comment: @styts Actually just displaying the users to html page

Comment: @TheDjangoNinja Actually am just asking the sample page. My original html file will load 25 queries. So it takes 15 seconds to load the page. How to reduce that\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First : optimize your db queries.

If you only want to display a couple db fields (`user.username` and `user.email` in your example) and don't need any of the model's method, use a `ValuesQuerySet` instead:

```
def myview(request):
    users = User.objects.values("username", "email")
    return render_to_response('pages/index1.html',  {'users': users,})
```

OTHO if you need related objects, use the ["select_related"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) keyword arg in your query to avoid the "n+1 queries" problem.

Once this is done, if your query returns hundreds or more records, you want to [paginate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/) the queryset. This is specially efficient with querysets as it uses the SQL `offset` and `limit` clauses so pagination is in fact done at the db level.

At this point you should have a significant boost already at least at the ORM/db level. If the rendering itself (template level) still takes too much time, it will be time to consider using the [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/).

Comment: Thank some what the time reduced, And my page hase some images as well it also takes long time to load.